# Orderby on SharePoint list item does not work

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to order a collection of list items with Microsoft Graph :

```
.../items?select=id&orderby=id%20desc
```

I've tried on multiple properties and with a space instead of `%20`. I've followed the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#orderby).

But ids are always ordered ascending. Am I doing anything wrong or is it a bug with Microsoft Graph ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$orderby` parameter is not currently supported by the [SharePoint endpoints](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/sharepoint%5C). At this time only `$select`, `$expand`, and `$filter` are supported.

I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding a request for this feature. It seems like it would be valuable when pulling a collection of `ListItem` resources.

---

As an aside, you're also missing the `$` prefix:

```
items?$select=id&$orderby=id desc
```

Ignoring the `$` prefix is only supported on the `beta` endpoint. Per the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters):

> **Note**: On the `beta` endpoint, the `$` prefix is optional.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `beta`. It is unstable and unsupported. That said, have you tried adding the `$`?

Comment: I have the same issue with v1.0 endpoint. Here is my request: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{sitename}/lists/{listname}/items?$select=id&$orderby=id desc. Order by is working well with other resources in graph api like /users

Comment: A lot of Graph endpoints are aggregated from other APIs behind the scenes. It isn't uncommon for some resources to support a different query parameter set. After some digging, it doesn't look like the `ListItem` collection supports `$OrderBy`

Comment: $count is not supported too on this endpoint, so i think the best way to order by id desc is to fetch all with &top=5000 and skiptoken and then order by yourself in your code.

Comment: The result is paged. Each page will contain a link to the next page in the result until you reach the final page (where no link is provided). It isn't a good idea to request a massive `$top` as it will have a serious performance hit. It is generally better to fetch by page. This allows you to construct your local objects in parallel with the next page request.

Comment: But if i need to order id desc this is the only way to fetch all the pages no ?

Comment: Thats correct. You just don't want to fetch pages with 5k of records per page.

Comment: Does anyone know if `$orderby` is supported yet?  I am coming across statements that it is supported if using ominous sounding headers such as ['Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/821510/microsoft-graph-sharepoint-lists-api-orderby-not-w) with caveats such as 'be warned that such queries may fail on large lists' (if it can't provide a reliable result, I am not sure why it is offered as a service).  In my tests with several related queries using `$expand=fields`, they always fail with a `400 Bad Request`.